# Can there be an edge with a positive capacity directly from the source to the destination in a network?

Tags: network-flow

I was hoping to use this in a proof of mine. I do not see any problems with this being the case, however, I have never run into example graphs with this so I was curious.

Comment: It depends on your definition of flow network I guess, but in all of the definitions I've seen, a flow network is an arbitrary directed graph. So I would say yes, an edge from the source to the sink is allowed.

Comment: Yes, no problem.